# How many paths can Apache IoTDB query multiple devices in one statement?

Tags: sql, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When querying multiple devices in Apache IoTDB, for example for query statement like `select * from root.test.dey 1, root.test. dey2 align by device`, I want to know how many paths I can put in one query statement in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit for the paths you queried from Apache IoTDB, therefore you can record the paths you need to query the most, and manipulate it to different servers or platforms that install IoTDB.